# pgbouncer throws Pooler Error: Auth Failed when using datagrip but NOT when using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, datagrip, pgbouncer

I have a postgres database (version 9.2) running on Centos 6.9.
I am running pgbouncer version 1.6.1

When I try connect to postgres using datagrip from my Mac, I get:

```
08P01: Error: Auth Failed
```

And I get on the server:

```
/var/log/pgbouncer.log

2021-05-21 18:29:02.644 7489 WARNING C-0x15cf078: postgres/jode@127.0.0.1:56254 Pooler Error: Auth failed
```

When I login to postgres using Pgadmin 4 from the same Mac and same settings, I get right in and there are no errors or warnings in pgbouncer.

What could the problem?

Comment: PgAdmin is not working via JDBC. So you need to configure pgBouncer to accept TCP/IP connections (see [similar dba exchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245784/pgbouncer-getting-auth-failing-when-trying-to-connect-using-psql))

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you add it as answer, I will mark it as the right answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PgAdmin is not working via JDBC. So you need to configure pgBouncer to accept TCP/IP connections (see [similar dba exchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245784/pgbouncer-getting-auth-failing-when-trying-to-connect-using-psql))